# Total number of stops for an elevator to serve certain people

Tags: c++, algorithm, interview-questions

I have seen this question asked around a bit, such as [this Code Review question in Java](/questions/111673/program-to-determine-total-stops-taken-by-elevator):

> Write an optimal program that would determine the total number of stops
>   a elevator has taken to serve X number of people. There is a elevator
>   in a building with M floors. This elevator can take a max of X people
>   at a time or max of total weight Y. Given that a set of people has
>   arrived and their weight and the floor they need to stop given how
>   many stops has the elevator taken to serve all the people. Consider
>   elevator serves in the first come first serve basis. (N people in Queue)

I am making this code review request to see if I can get any feedback on my C++ implementation.

```
const int max_number_of_ppl = 3; // X
const float max_weight = 250.0;  // Y
const int number_of_floors = 5; // M

// assume person array is 0,1,....N-1 -> so N people
// people are in a queue , find total number of stops 
int solution(const int &N,const std::vector<int> &weight,const std::vector<int> &floor)
{
    int idx = 0;
    float last_weight = 0.0;
    int last_count = 0;
    std::set<int> stops;
    int stop_count = 0;
    while(idx < N)
    {
        //lift full, dont put any more ppl
        if(last_count + 1 > max_number_of_ppl || last_weight + weight[idx] > max_weight)
        {
            stop_count += static_cast<int>(stops.size());
            stops.clear();
            last_weight = 0.0;
            last_count = 0;

        }

        //fill lift with the person
        stops.insert(floor.at(idx));
        last_count++;
        last_weight += weight.at(idx);

        //fetch next person
        idx++;
    }

    //handle last lift session
    if(stops.size() >0)
    {
        stop_count += static_cast<int>(stops.size());
    }

    return stop_count;
}
```

Simple test:

```
int main()
{
    int N = 6;
    std::vector<int> weight;
    std::vector<int> stops;
    weight.emplace_back(100);
    weight.emplace_back(70);
    weight.emplace_back(60);
    weight.emplace_back(190);
    weight.emplace_back(100);
    weight.emplace_back(10);

    stops.emplace_back(5);
    stops.emplace_back(5);
    stops.emplace_back(5);
    stops.emplace_back(4);
    stops.emplace_back(3);
    stops.emplace_back(3);

    std::cout<<solution(N,weight,stops);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd like to suggest you use a `for`-loop, since it would be easier to see, that you're going to increment the loop variable in every iteration independent of any conditions. Then you could also exchange your `idx` variable for `i` since the first does not convey more or less semantics than the second and it is somewhat unwritten convention.

Next: Why use a `static_cast<int>`for incrementing the `stop_count`? I think you would not need that, if you defined `stop_count` as a `size_t`.

Also: Was there some sort of requirement that `solution()` takes `N` as an argument? You could get rid of that parameter, since you have the `weight`-vector, which in turn has a `size()`.

Furthermore: What is the parameter `M` (`number_of_floors`) going to be used for? I do not see much use for it other than boundary checking in the program, in a real world scenario no one could press button *10* in a 5-story building anyway.